# How to transfer files between Ubuntu machines on other networks?

Tags: server

So I need to share files using the terminal of Ubuntu to another ubuntu user. We are not in the same network, how can I share a file to that user using the terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with scp, sftp, rsync, or anything that uses SSH?

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect via ssh I would use scp (secure copy). It isn’t great for copying multiple files at a time, but for just a few it’s fine. The man page is here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp